# React - Laravel API CORS

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

I have a Laravel API on my localhost (http://localhost:8000)
And I have React APP on my localhost (http://localhost:3000)

When I try to post Auth with Axios, I've error that;

"Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/login due to access control checks.
http://localhost:8000/api/login
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Network Error"

I'm sharing you my Laravel Cors codes and my react codes.
What could be problem?

When I try to post with "postman" Response Headers show me Access-Control-Allow-Origin is allowed by "*".

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'cors'
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class // <-- add this line
    ];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
```

Middleware/CORS.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
  }
}
```

And my basic React Axios call;

```
function loginWithEmailSaga(payload) {
  const { email, password } = payload;
  axios.post(
    loginUrl,
    { email, password }
  )
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

I don't see any reason why It gives CORS error.
Everything seemed "allowed". What could be the problem? What can I do to handle that thing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"
```

Make sure restart the server of React after adding this line

Comment: I used like below. But didnt work. I  restarted React after enter this code. {
  "name": "enlite_prime",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "description": "React.js fullstack web template for expert and experienced fullstack developer",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=5",
    "node": ">=8.15.1"
  },
  "author": "Enlite Prime Team",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",

Comment: Don't add localhost:8000 to loginUrl, mention only route (Ex: loginUrl = "api/login" )